# How to deploy image to EC2 usign Docker and Circleci. CI CD

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, continuous-deployment, circleci, amazon-ecr

I am trying to implement CI/CD. So far what I have is a CI using CircleCI, and

> circleci/aws-ecr@6.15.0

orb, so when I push to master the image is created and pushed to ECR. That works perfect, but what I want to implement is the deployment.
I think that I am not searching well in google, but I can not find any tutorial or explanation of how to do it.
I read that the orb

> circleci/aws-ecs@01.4.0

and seems to do the job but I really dont know how to proceed.

This is my yaml file:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@4.1.0
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@6.15.0
  aws-ecs: circleci/aws-ecs@01.4.0
workflows:
  build_and_push_image:
    jobs:
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          repo: node.js-api
          tag: "latest,v0.1.${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}"
          dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
          path: .
      - aws-ecs/deploy-service-update:
          requires:
            - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image
          family: "${AWS_RESOURCE_NAME_PREFIX}-service"
          cluster-name: "${AWS_RESOURCE_NAME_PREFIX}-cluster"
          container-image-name-updates: "container=${AWS_RESOURCE_NAME_PREFIX}-service,tag=${CIRCLE_SHA1}"
```

Error:

> An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the
> DescribeTaskDefinition operation: Unable to describe task definition.

What I want to achieve is an automated deploy, I choose CircleCI because I thought it would be a good option also with my bitbucket repo, but if there is another way to achieve this I am totally open to hear suggestions.

Thanks!!

Comment: Well, for one, you have an error in your configuration, `01.4.0`, whereas it should be `1.4.0`. What do you mean when you say you don't know how to proceed? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Oh, Thank you for the error I will check that. What I want to achieve is basically after creating the image and pushing it to ECR repo, run it in the instance. So far I do it manually, I pull the image, and write the command docker run ....I updated the post with the error I am getting..

Comment: Were you able to fix it?